# Writing to a single colour channel with image_load_store

Tags: opengl, glsl, image-unit

The image_load_store extension provides load/store functions with `*vec4` access only. If I have `layout(rgba32f) uniform image2D myimage;` for example, it seems like I have to write to the entire pixel at once:

```
imageStore(myimage, coord, vec4(1,1,1,1));
```

and if I want to set only the red channel to `1`, I need to do this:

```
vec4 pixel = imageLoad(myimage, coord);
pixel.r = 1;
imageStore(myimage, coord, pixel);
```

which introduces a fair amount of overhead with the extra read.

**Is there a mechanism I can use to write only to a specific channel?**

Something similar to `glColorMask`, or perhaps binding the data with a different format such as a larger `GL_R32F` `image2D` or `imageBuffer`? If so, what are some of the overhead implications (e.g. conversion/transfer/cache issues)?